# How to download only the main expansion file in Android?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I would like to force the app to download the main expansion file before it can be used, and optionally download the patch file if the user wants more assets.

However, the download function provided by the Downloader Library `DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context.getApplicationContext(), pendingIntent, DownloaderServiceHelper.class);` seems to force downloading both main and patch files.

How do I choose to download either the main or patch file?

Answer (score 0):

i am  also looking for same but i think we can do this .For downloading patch file we need to call a broadcast receiver so instead of calling broadcast receiver in main Activity we can call this receiver at our own conditions.
Please let me know if you achieve this .

And i also want to know can we create .OBB file from eclipse.

Comment: Did you find out how this is done? Please let me know